# ssrs color background color of a null column

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a table like this:

```
[Name] [Position]
a          0
b          1
c          2
d          3
e          4
f          5
```

I create a chart with [Name] as rows and [Position] as columns and count of position as value.
Like this:

```
     0   1  2  3  4  5
a    1
b        1
c           1
d              1
e                 1
f                    1
```

I would like to make all of the column where [Position] = 2 to be blue, and all others to be white.  I cannot figure out how I can do this because the rows do not have a value at that position e.g.  Position(e) = 4, and has no value at 2.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Haven't got SSRS here to try it, but perhaps it'll work if you select the column group in the designer, and set an expression for the background-color on that such as `IIF(Fields!Position.Value = 2, "#0000FF", "#FFFFFF")`?

Comment: That is what I tried originally, but the issue is that this statement only works for rows that have Position.Value = 2.  In the example, say for 'b' Position.Value = 1, but there is still a cell at position 2 that does not get colored.  WHen I use this expression, only the cell c2 gets filled

Comment: Ahh ohw, yikes. Can't think of any solution then (barring generating values for position 2 on all rows)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that has this same issue, you can actually get the value of a specific box like this:  `ReportItems("Textbox600").Value`

Just replace 600 with the cell name.  The name is displayed right above the toolbar for the properties box when a cell is selected.

In this case, Textbox600 is the [Position], so the expression for this cells background color looks like this:

```
Iif(ReportItems("Textbox600").Value = 2, "Blue", "White")
```

Answer (score 1):

C2 is the only one filled as that is the only cell where data exists in column "2". Possibly you can cross join your Name and Position to generate values for all cells, e.g.

```
SELECT 
    a.name,
    b.position,
    CASE WHEN c.name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS position_count
FROM 
(
(SELECT [name] FROM #temp) a
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT [position] FROM #temp)b
) 
LEFT JOIN #temp c ON a.name = c.name and b.position = c.position
```

returns

```
name position position_count
---- -------- --------------
a    0        1
a    1        0
a    2        0
a    3        0
a    4        0
a    5        0
b    0        0
b    1        1
b    2        0
b    3        0
b    4        0
```

etc.

That should let you use the expression to set the background-color on the column group. You could add an expression on the cells to suppress the "zero" values.